# How to recover overwritten bash profile

Tags: linux, macos, bash, homebrew

I installed homebrew with `brew install wget` and when I opened my `.bash_profile` it was some file I had never seen before full of homebrew's things. My aliases are still working, but I was wondering where I could find them since they're not in the txt file anymore.

Comment: Is this on Mac OS X?  Do you run Time Machine backups?  If not, are you going to from here on?  If you do have such backups, recovery is straight-forward.  If you don't, you're into interesting territory.  Make sure you have backups before installing software, just in case the installation goes dolally — or even works perfectly but doesn't do what you expected with your configuration.  (It's a separate discussion "why is Brew tampering with your profile" — in my book, it shouldn't; or, at the least, it should ask permission first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with OSX, but I guess your old bash settings could have been backed up somewhere, because your aliases are still working. Try searching for files/directories named "bash*".

Comment: I was able to find a list of my aliases and added them to the new one. I knew they had to be there somewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should try using a file recovery program. it is possible the alias is referring to the location on the HDD and that the file still exists, even if the file with that name isn't accessible anymore.

a file recovery program may be a good option.